# '->' doesnt doesn't work for structure inside structure

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct {
    char name[3];
    bool initial_state;
    bool final_state;
    struct TRANSITION *transitions;
    int numberTransition;
} STATE;

typedef struct {
    char c;
    struct STATE *destination;
} TRANSITION;

STATE *create_state(char *name, bool is_initial, bool is_final);
void add_transition(STATE *source, char sign, STATE *dest);
void destroy_state(STATE **pp_state);

int main(void) {
    STATE *state1 = create_state("S'0", true, false);
    STATE *state2 = create_state("S'1", true, false);
    STATE *state3 = create_state("S'2", true, false);
    printf("%s  ", state1->name);
    printf("%d  ", state1->initial_state);
    printf("%d  ", state1->final_state);
    add_transition(state1, 'A', state2);
    TRANSITION *transitions = state1->transitions;
    printf("%c  ", transitions[0].c);
}
```

As you can see, I access the `state1` structure. And it actually works for `name`, `initial_state` and `final_state`. But for some reason it doesn't work for `state1->transitions`. I guess because it is a structure itself, I have to do something else.

What is wrong with this line?:

```
TRANSITION *transitions = state1->transitions;
```

Comment: `But for some reason it doesn't work`...what doesn;t work?

Comment: TRANSITION *transitions = state1->transitions; <-- this

Comment: You're not getting the point...what do you mean by does not work?

Comment: Do you get an error message from the compiler, or unexpected runtime behavior?

Comment: The expression `transitions[0]` is not a string.

Comment: I get an exception when I compile it. It says that it is an "initialization from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: If you get build-errors, please include the *complete* error output in the question body, in full and unedited, including any informational notes. Also, showing an actual a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem helps. There are too much missing from the code you show.

Comment: @DennisvonEich Use `struct TRANSITION *transitions = state1->transitions;` instead.

Comment: @DennisvonEich Alternatively use `typedef struct statustransition STATUSTRANSITION;` at the top, and replace `struct TRANSITION *transitions;` with `TRANSITION *transitions;` in the `struct`'s declaration.

Comment: Also note that `name[3]` is not enough to store `"S'0"`, which is 4-bytes long: you need `name[4]` to give sufficient space to the null terminator.

Comment: Where are the `TRANSITION` and `STATE` *structures*? You have type-aliases of those names, but no *structures* named that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i don't know what you mean. the structures are at the top

Comment: @DennisvonEich That only defines the type-aliases by that name, not actual *structure* names. See [Paul Ogilvie answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35682738/440558) for an *imcomplete* solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that structure names, like `struct STATE`, are living in their own namespace, separate from the rest of the C namespace where things like type-aliases lives (by type-alias I mean the symbols created with `typedef`).

If you do e.g.

```
typedef struct STATE_STRUCTURE { ... } STATE_TYPE;
```

you define *two* different symbols, first the structure name `STATE_STRUCTURE` and then the type-alias `STATE_TYPE`. To use `STATE_STRUCTURE` you use the `struct` keywords as in

```
struct STATE_STRUCTURE *state;
```

You can't use the structure name without actually defining a structure name. And this is what you are missing from your structure definitions.

Also note that since the structure names lives in their own namespaces, like I said before, you can have a structure name be the same as the type-alias:

```
typedef struct STATE { ... } STATE;
```

---

My proposed solution for your problem is to use *forward declarations* of both the structure and type-alias names:

```
typedef struct STATE STATE;
typedef struct TRANSITION TRANSITION;
```

This tells the compiler that there are structures with the names `STATE` and `TRANSITION`, and also that the are type-alias of those structures with the same name.

Then you simply defined the structures themselves, and since we already declared the type-aliases you can use them inside the structures:

```
struct STATE
{
    char name[3];
    bool initial_state;
    bool final_state;
    TRANSITION *transitions;
    int numberTransition;
};

struct TRANSITION
{
    char c;
    STATE *destination;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you try to print the transition can't be right: transitions[0] is a struct, not a string. If you meant to output the `char c` struct member, use:

```
printf("%c  ", transitions[0].c);
```

There's also the issue of undefined types. If you use `typedef struct { } FOO` then `struct FOO` defines a separate (incomplete) type. But you still need to tell the compiler what `TRANSITION` is while you are defining `STATE`. One way to around this is to forward-declare `TRANSITION` like this:

```
typedef struct transition TRANSITION;
typedef struct
{
    ....
    TRANSITION *transitions;
} STATE;

/* TRANSITION is already a typedef for struct transition.
   no need to add a typedef here */
struct transition
{
    char c;
    STATE *destination;
};
```

Comment: Yes, i fixed it. But that doesnt work too. My compiler says that its the wrong usage for "undefined type  »struct TRANSITION«"

Answer (score 1):

That is because in `STATE` you declare a `struct TRANSITION *transitions` but the declaration of `TRANSITION` does not have the `struct` keyword. Use:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[3];
    bool initial_state;
    bool final_state;
    struct TRANSITION *transitions;
    int numberTransition;
} STATE;

typedef struct TRANSITION
{
    char c;
    struct STATE *destination;
} TRANSITION;
```

Comment: Oh what the heck. That eliminated every exception I got.

Comment: This is a good start, but kind of incomplete. Where's the `STATE` *structure* name? Where are the forward declarations needed?

Comment: @Joachim-pileborg, they reference each other, so at least one must have a forward declaration.